# Problem reading an EEPROM chip using the I2C protocol

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, c, eeprom

I am trying to read an EEPROM chip that supports the ***I2C*** protocol (cannot tell the IC model number as it is not printed). For sure it supports the I2C protocol, since I wrote a code to detect it using the I2C library and the device address I got it return is ***0x51***. Now I am trying to write a code that reads data from this IC chip. The code is as follows:

```
#include <Wire.h>

int addr = 0;

void setup() {
    Wire.begin(); // initialise the connection
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {}
    delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  byte deviceAddress = 0x51;
  byte data = readData(addr, deviceAddress);
  Serial.print(data, HEX);
  Serial.print(" ");
  addr++;
  if(addr%16 == 0) {
     Serial.print('\n');
  }
  // check for 1Kbits first
  if (addr%128 == 0) {
     Serial.println("round complete");
     Serial.println();
     addr = 0;
  }
  delay(100);
}

byte readData(int address, int deviceAddress) {
  // sending device address
  Wire.beginTransmission(deviceAddress);
  Wire.write(address);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom((short int)deviceAddress, 1);
  if(Wire.available()) {
    byte data = Wire.read();
    return data;  
  }
  return 0xAA; // random data
}
```

The problem I am facing is, I get back the address (from which I want to read the data) as the data itself (For e.g. read(0) returns 0, read(1) returns 1 and so on). I even tried to debug the I2C communication using the logic analyzer (Saleae logic in this case). A screenshot is shown below.

[image]

The screenshot shows the logic for a read operation from a single address (0x78), but the story holds for each and every address i.e. I get back the address instead of the data from the address.

The output of the above code is as follows:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F 
>   10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 
>   20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 
>   30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 
>   40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 
>   50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 
>   60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F 
>   70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F 
>   round complete

Can you help me identifying what possibly I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: How about using a 16-bit address? Here is a link to a driver that I have written for Cosa; https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/AT24CXX/AT24CXX.hh

Comment: How many legs (pins) does the chip have?

Comment: I agree with Mikael too, you could try sending a 16-bit address. For example, send a zero first, then an address. In any case, can you be certain that the chip does not happen to have 0x00, 0x01, etc. inside its memory?

Comment: @MikaelPatel: I will give a try with 16-bit address and let you know what the results are.

Comment: @NickGammon: Just to make sure that the contents are not 0x00, 0x01, etc. I tried to perform a write operation to the chip. But the result for reading after a write, remains the same. Maybe I have to try using 16-bit addresses as you suggested as well.

Comment: @NickGammon: I tried using the 16 bit addresses, but to no success. The data I got in return is all zeroes. Maybe because now I am getting back the first 8 bits which I am writing, i.e. 0x00. I was also looking at the I2c library that you suggested in your blog. http://dsscircuits.com/articles/arduino-i2c-master-library. Can you help me in understanding, what exactly is registerAddress here? Its used in many functions of this library, for.e.g.I2c.write(address, registerAddress, *data, numberBytes). Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the device, but some have a register where writing something to it causes internal bits to be set. Honestly, trying to help write to / read from an unknown device is almost impossible. For $5 you could buy a chip that you know the part number of and can get the datasheet for.

Comment: Ahh OK. I was doing a reverse engineering project and the chip is in fact a COB. I have to then decap it somehow and see underneath. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the address as two bytes, one by one.

Do not do:

```
Wire.write(address);
```

Rather, do:

```
Wire.write((uint8_t)(address >> 8)); // MSB
Wire.write((uint8_t)(address & 0xFF)); // LSB
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you should split

```
Wire.write(address);
```

into

```
Wire.write((int)(eeaddress >> 8)); // MSB
Wire.write((int)(eeaddress & 0xFF)); // LSB
```

I am working on a similar project right now. I have searched through many different codes and libraries and found the following to work the best:
https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/I2CEEPROM

I am using the 24LC1025 who's datasheet can be found here: 
http://www.microchip.com/datasheet/24LC1025

I am using the 1Mb version and it uses 0x51 and 0x50 becuase it has two pages. I suspect you will find your chip to at least be similar because of the I2C Address you listed. You may have a smaller version of the same chip that only uses the one address.

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific chip info this will be difficult.

However, my experience with EEPROMs and I2C is that the first action is to write a command, then write the parameter(s) for that command, then read the response.

Often, there is a status register in the EEPROM that needs to be read (by writing a command, then reading the response) to determine if the EEPROM is ready to receive a different command, like writing to set the address for a read/or/write, then the actual read command.